# Сессии для отправки сообщений и авторизации

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуйте, в сессиях в php совсем не смыслю, вот надо чат написать... Вопрос: можно ли использовать сессии для отправки сообщения и вообще как авторизацию, без профилей? Например, человек входит в чат, заполняя логин и пароль, если пароль и логин совпали, то в сессию помещается логин и открывается способность отправлять сообщения. Отправляя собщение, в переменную логин подойдёт сессия с логином.

```
$login = $_SESSION['login'].
```

И отправляя сообщения, пока сессия существует, имя отправителя будет по имени сессии... Можно ли такое сделать и безопасно ли это? Или лучше создать, как сейчас сделал профиль, и в нём форма для отправки сообщения.

Answer (score 3):

> Можно конечно, но это не очень безопасно. Не забывайте, что данные в сессии легко подменить.

что что простите ? Как это можно легко подменить данные в сессии ?

Раскажите поподробнее пожалуйста, а то я лес темный ...

ЗЫ: специально для вас расскажу что сессии как раз используют куки для идентификации сессии.

По поводу вопроса:

> ... без профилей ...
> ... заполняя логин и пароль, если пароль и логин совпали...

как так ? Если профиля нет, по чем тогда сравнивать будет что логин и пароль верный ?

> то в сессию помещается логин и открывается способность отправлять сообщения

Обычно так и делают, все правильно.

> ... и безопасно ли это ?

Вполне

> Или лучше создать, как сейчас сделал профиль

Простите, а что вы собственно подразумеваете под "профилем" ? А то у нас терминология не совпадает :)

Comment: Да, видать терминология не только у Вас не совпала )

Comment: Вся безопасность упирается в эти хранимые параметры. Если добавить что-то вроде <b>$_SESSION["dostup"]='Развлекайся'</b>, то это бред. Хранить нужно не только логин, но и пароль в виде какого-нибудь хэша, причем отличного от того, в котором он хранится в БД. Желательно еще как-нибудь организовать временную привязку к ip-адресу.
Например, <pre><code>
$_SESSION["password"]=md5($user_pass.$ip);
if(md5($user_pass.$ip)==$_SESSION["password"]) {/* Юзер залогинен, пускаем */};
</code></pre>

Comment: Это называется параноя. Вы сами пишете туда значение. Зачем на каждый запрос использовать тяжеловесную функцию md5 ? Конечно, проверку на ip можно добавить (но не нужно), при этом хранить ip в открытом виде, а не хеш. Не нужно потому что ip может менятся, это нормально, при этом авторизация не пропустит пользователя. Не думаю что они будут от этого в восторге.

$_SESSION["dostup"]='Развлекайся' это бред, но бред не потому что это не правильно, вплане решения, а бредово в плане значения.

это куда более читабельнее

$_SESSION["dostup"]='1';

if ($_SESSION["dostup"]=='1') { ... пускаем ...}

Comment: > Если добавить что-то вроде

т.е если кто-то из пользователей сможет добавить 

$_SESSION["dostup"]='Развлекайся'

в код на сайте ?

Если так - то если у пользователя есть доступ к редактированию исходниов сайто тут уже любая авторизация не поможет :)

Comment: Итог - вернулись к возможности получения имени сессии. Мой пример от этого спасает, сессия просто не будет активна с другого ip и скрипт потребует новую авторизацию. 

А вот если Вы сделаете такой же финт со своей циферкой один, добавив ее в куки... Хотя, это уже лет 10 не смешно...

И кстати, с каких пор функция `md5` стала "тяжеловесной"?

Comment: md5 легкая до безобразия, но это, мягко говоря,не лучшее решение шифрования пароля

Comment: Ну насчет не лучшего решения спорить не буду. Хотя сам использую комплекс из хэшей `md4` и `md5` в своеобразной последовательности и с мусором.

Answer (score 0):

Смотри. Нужно создать в базе таблицу типо этой...

```
id | user | password | protect_key
==================================
1  | Boris| mamba    | fefse7f67s
```

Когда пользователь будет вводить логин и пароль для авторизации то скрипту нужно проверить совпадают ли они с теми что в базе данных. И если совпадают то генерировать 'ключ защиты'(protect_key) который запихиваем в сессию и в базу для того пользователя которого мы авторизировали. Далее уже все действия будут совершатся только через этот ключ так как это ниболее безопасно. То есть чтобы отправить сообщение с полями `to`, `msg` мы будем отправлять с ним также наш ключ $_SESSION['protect_key'] и по этому ключу смотреть есть ли  пользователь с таким ключом в базе и по ключу вытаскивать его id для отправки сообщения.

Comment: можно ищо более усложнить защиту добавив в таблицу поле `session_time` в которое будем записывать время создания сессии. Ну а дальше уже будем давать како-то определённое время существования сессии. И если время существования сессии будет больше заданого то удаляем сессию.

Answer (score -2):

Можно конечно, но это не очень безопасно. Не забывайте, что данные в сессии легко подменить. Сам по себе факт авторизации можно хранить в определенном виде определенное время в куках. В сессии же для удобного доступа можно хранить ID пользователя.

Comment: Вообще-то куки подменить проще... Да и с точки зрения безопасности особой разницы нет...

Comment: Эм, а как, если не секрет, можно подменить сессии?

Comment: Угадать (телепатия у программистов развивается при общении с заказчиками) или украсть ее имя. Ну и верить, что она еще будет активна к тому моменту, как будет применяться...)

Comment: Тоже тиресно, как можно подменить сессию или куки хотя бы предваритедьно их не получив? На картах таро раскидывать?

Comment: Мде... не люблю минусы коментам ставить!

Comment: Эх... Понаберут по объявлению...

Классический прием угона сессии: при кривых настройках сервера и отключенных куках у пользователя, имя сессии пишется как гет-параметрам ко всем ссылкам страницы. Пользователь может захотеть отправить такую ссылку другу и скопирует он ее, разумеется, с этим параметром. Если при этом параметры авторизации хранятся в сессии, то выше названный друг попадет на сайт с учетной записью отправителя такой ссылки.

Ну а куки - тут уж надо их все-таки нагло красть. XSS в помощь...

Comment: Методом тыка, методом тыка... Как известно от дурака защиты нет ^^

Comment: Ну методом тыка все же происходит операция получения сессии или куки для дальнейшей подмены? Не так ли?

Comment: Сессию не надо подменять. По своей сути сессия - это файл на сервере. Нужно просто узнать ее имя и сообщить скрипту, чтобы он ее использовал.

Comment: Если быть точным то происходит это следующим образом - допустим пользователь `admin` авторизовался и естественно получил какой-то `sid`, т.е. появляется вероятность что можно подобрать ключ к сессии (а уже передавать его труда не составит) и таким образом получить права админа без авторизации, со всемы вытекающими :)<br>
Провернуть это довольно таки сложно, да и отслидить такие попытки, при желании, не так сложно... Но тем не менее вероятность то остается ;)

Comment: Мде... нет понту спорить... Имя сессии может быть равно

md5('взломщик пашол в }|{опу') и значение 'взломщик дыбил' 

надрыайтесь)

Comment: Гм... Сделай это - поставь на все сессии одинаковые индификаторы - пользователи тебя полюбят....)

Comment: Я как правило не использую меньше 5 сессий для идентификации! И они не мертвые а динамические.

Comment: А почему всего 5?<br>
Даешь 100 xDDD<br><br>
Если серьезно - "шо занадто то нездраво"

Comment: >Если при этом параметры авторизации хранятся в сессии, то выше названный друг попадет на сайт с учетной записью отправителя такой ссылки.

как **это** объясняет 

>Не забывайте, что данные в сессии легко подменить.

это?